# Symfony Database-No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm following a guide online to make a registration form and when it comes to generating an entity called member I issue this command in the cmd:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

All is good at this point. It then asks me to make the entity shortcut name. I call it `AppBundle:User` and it returns this error.

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could 
  be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target 
  machine actively refused it.

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target 
  machine actively refused it.
```

This is my config.yml file

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the 
app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
    resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
    strict_requirements: ~
form: ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation: { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
default_locale: '%locale%'
trusted_hosts: ~
session:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
fragments: ~
http_method_override: true
assets: ~
php_errors:
    log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
cache:  false

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
```

And my parameter.yml file

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_host:     127.0.0.1
database_port:     ~
database_name:     some_db_name
database_user:     your_db_username
database_password: your_db_password
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Have you started the mysql service on your local machine? Usually when I get this error it's because I forgot to do that.

Comment: Figured it out thank you, I was just being stupid and forgot to reinstall mysql services since I last rebooted my laptop :P. Thank you though.